# How to connect ground layer to library component vias that should be ground in Eagle?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

[image]

This is the thermal configuration recommended for a stepper motor driver. Although, it's not connecting to the ground layer. Most resources online recommend a method of using a smash tool in the component's footprint. I cannot find the smash tool in my version of Eagle.

I want to have the whole underside connected to ground like this:

[image]

I used two rectangles over the vias. I'm not sure if that's going to work though. How to get all the vias to connect to one signal (such as ground)?

Comment: They've all got different net names associated with each via so either make them all the same in the library or connect them all together on the schematic.

Comment: I cannot make them all the same name. It will only allow one name per via: https://i.imgur.com/SQkpETP.png

Comment: The pads can have different names, but you will need to assign each of these GND pads to a symbol pin when making assignments in the library device editor. You can use the same symbol pin to connect to multiple pads.

Comment: "assign each of these GND pads to a symbol pin" How? These vias on the footprint do not have a corresponding symbol on the library schematic.

Comment: @adamaero they are pads on the footprint, yes. Library devices have a footprint and a symbol. You tell eagle how the pads and symbol pins connect up. If you don't have a pin on the symbol for these vias to connect to, you will need to add one. Otherwise eagle will have no way of knowing what signal to connect them to.

Comment: Are you saying I need to use the PADS package import? https://i.imgur.com/ldHdBRp.png

Comment: No, not PADS. Right click on the symbol there and select "Edit Device" - it should list each package and the corresponding pin connections. You'll see that all your GND1/GND2/GND3 pads are currently unconnected there, so you'll need to either assign them to one of the existing symbol pins, or add a new pin to the symbol (e.g. called `TH`)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I was in the wrong version of the device. I thought I was working in the first default version (but it was the third).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I saw every time I tried to edit:

[image]

The footprint I am using is actually tied to a different version:

[image]

Under that third version, the added ground vias can be assigned:

[image]